# Move toolbar to top of relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, android-toolbar

I am trying to put my button in the center, but keep my toolbar at the top. At the moment both are in the middle because of the gravity `"center"`.

Is there a way to do this without using padding attributes? Otherwise it will look different on other screen sizes.

Here is my `main_activity`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, change to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="New Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try below xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#2196F3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="New Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` 
for your button

for the tool bar try `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate layout for your toolbar and set its gravity to top.